# Command to know text,BSS etc fields of an executable

Tags: linux, gcc, stack

Is there any Linux command to show code, BSS, Stack etc of a compiled C-program

Comment: This question is all about the linker output really, and thus has nothing to do with the C language. Removing it from the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size(1)` can show you the sizes of all the segments of an executable.

Sample output:

```
$ size /bin/ls
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  97892     972    3136  102000   18e70 /bin/ls
```